# how to set the column name in the web part property edit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, content-query-web-part

I have to use the custom column in the web part property.

I have to set the **EventDate** column, I have set as EventDate or [EventDate] or EventDate [CustomColumn];

And facing Error as-

```
The site or list column "[EventDate]" does not exist or is not valid.
```

Comment: what's the list type and web part type that you used ? also is this a CQWP ? Please add more details to let participants can answer faster

Comment: It's an **Calendar** type List, Content Query Web Part and it is CQWP.

Comment: are you use custom item style or default and what's its name ?

Comment: Yes, it's custom style and name **UpcomingEvent**.

Comment: should you share with me the code of your custom style , you should make sure that Event data is placed there

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:format-date(substring-before(@EventDate, ' '), 'M/d', 'en-us')" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44298/discussion-between-ram-and-m-qassas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our conversation above and at the discussion .

The issue is related to your code for this field in your custom Item Style.

You should be aware of the internal column name that you have used in your custom Item Style. should be the same internal Column name at your List.

Comment: Yes,
It was the internal name issue as I noticed earlier text.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the column's internal name is different **StartDate**.
Now it's working fine.